# the use of the word more "time" in context

Tags: grammar

Tell me please if I constructed the following sentence correctly:

> There are **5 times more** men in the club than women.

I heard people say:

> There are **5 times as many** men in the club as women.

Tell me please if my sentence sounds natural.

Comment: With ***five times*** both constructions are fine. But with, for example, ***twice***, you can only use ***...as many***, not ***more***. (And *never ever* think of using ***thrice*** in such contexts today! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of your example sentences

> There are 5 **times more** men in the club than women.
>   There are 5 **times as many** men in the club as women.

are correct, meaning that for every female member there are five male members.
But for other comparisons, you will need to say it in a specific way

> <s>There are **twice more** men in the club as women.</s>
>   There are **double the number** of men in the club as women.
>   There are **twice as many** men in the club as women.

and

> There are **triple the number** of men in the club as women.
>   There are **quadruple the number** of men in the club as women.

but once you get over 4, the *pattern* becomes your example sentences.

If you need to keep the *pattern* the same throughout your comparison, you might say

> Women are outnumbered 2 to 1 in the club.
>   Women are outnumbered 3 to 1 in the club.
>   Women are outnumbered 5 to 1 in the club.
>   Women are outnumbered 100 to 1 in the club.

Answer (score 0):

Your sentence sounds perfectly natural.

You can use the same form for any number, but see the answer given by 'Peter' for some nice ways to vary your writing.